# Chef/ruby: import all templates from template subdirectory into single directory on a node

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

Using a simple template block, is there a way to copy all template files in a `templates/default/SubDir/` (`templates/default/SubDir/*`) to a single location (`/tmp/`)?
Here is an example block:

```
template '/tmp/...' do
    source 'default/SubDir/...'
    owner node['attribute']['os_user']
    group node['attribute']['os_group']
    mode '0755'
end
```

EDIT: these are all xml files and I assume that I would not be adding the `.erb` extension to the template files, as that would require me to mention each template file name so that i can revert them back to .xml (as apposed to recursively copying the templates to the server).

NOTE: If this is not supported, then is there any recommended approach requiring strait ruby code?

---

EDIT: I am going to try making an aray of template files and see if that would work if I were to copy the entire array to the node.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating an array with the objects(templates) I needed to copy to the server.. it looks something like this:

```
auth_schemas = ['file1.xml','file2.xml','file3.xml','file4.xml','file5.xml','file6.xml','file7.xml','file8.xml','file9.xml','file10.xml']
        auth_schemas.each do |schemaFile|
          template "/tmp/#{schemaFile}" do
            source "path/to/SubDir/#{schemaFile}"
            owner node['attribute']['os_user']
            group node['attribute']['os_group']
            mode '0755'
          end
        end
```

Worked Like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not supported. Some additional characters because SO forces me to.

Comment: Is there any recommended approach requiring strait ruby code?